# Find the parabola of the form $y=ax^2+b$ which best fits the points $(1,0), (4,4), (5,8)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

by minimizing the sum of squares, $S$, given by
$$S=(a+b)^2 + (16a+b−4)^2 + (25a+b−8)^2$$

**My work so far**

The variables are a and b, so we set

$$\frac{∂S}{∂a}=2(a+b)+32(16a+b−4)+50(25a+b−8)=0$$

and

$$\frac{∂S}{∂b}=2(a+b)+2(16a+b−4)+2(25a+b−8)=0.$$

Collecting terms, we get

$$1764a+84b−528=0$$

and

$$84a+6b−24 = 0,$$

At this point, I'm stuck. I checked the solution in the textbook, but was unsure how they were calculated. What would be the first step? Would it be using the least squares approximation?

**Solution**

and solving for a and b gives

$$a=\frac{16}{49}$$

and

$$b=\frac{-4}{7}$$

Since there is only one critical point and S is unbounded as $a,b → ∞$, this critical point is the global minimum. Therefore, the best fitting parabola is

$$y=\frac{16}{49}$$

and

$$x=\frac{-4}{7}$$

Comment: The parabola is $y = \frac{16}{49}x^2 - \frac{4}{7}$

Comment: Your work directly (by solving the simultaneous equations in a and b) leads to the solution in the textbook, so what are you confused about?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks for that. I just worked out the simultaneous equations in a and b and got the solution. I just was unsure about which method to use.

Comment: What criterion is being used for the notion of "best" fit? Least squares is not the only game in town.

Comment: @Jessie could I ask how did you get to solve for a and b? The textbook that I'm following, skipped the process and just landed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given set of $n$ points $(x_i,y_y)$, $i=1,\dots,n$,
the parameters of the best fit parabola $y(x)=a_2x^2+a_1 x+a0$
can be found as:

\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
n       & s_x     & s_{x^2}\\
s_x     & s_{x^2} & s_{x^3}\\
s_{x^2} & s_{x^3} & s_{x^4}
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
s_y \\ s_{xy} \\ s_{x^2y}
\end{bmatrix}
.
\end{align}

where

\begin{align} 
s_{x}&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
,\quad
s_{x^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
,\quad
s_{x^3}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3
,\quad
s_{x^4}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4
,\\
s_{y}&=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i
,\quad
s_{xy}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i
,\quad
s_{x^2y}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2y_i
.
\end{align}

For the set of three points $(1,0),(4,4),(5,8)$,
$a_0=\tfrac43$,
$a_1=-2$,
$a_2=\tfrac23$.

[image]

In a special case where the parameter $a_1$ is forsd to be zero,
the solution simplifies
by eliminating all corresponding items
to

\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\ a_2
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
n       & s_{x^2}\\
s_{x^2} & s_{x^4}
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
s_y \\ s_{x^2y}
\end{bmatrix}
.
\end{align}

For the set of three points $(1,0),(4,4),(5,8)$,
we have $n=3$,
$x=[1,4,5]^{\mathsf{T}}$,
$y=[0,4,8]^{\mathsf{T}}$,
$s_{x^2}=42$,
$s_{x^4}=882$,
$s_{y}=12$,
$s_{x^2y}=264$,

and

\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\ a_2
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
3       & 42 \\
42 & 882
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
12 \\ 264
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1       & -1/21 \\
-1/21 & 1/294
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
12 \\ 264
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-4/7  \\ 16/49
\end{bmatrix}
,
\end{align}
so
$a_0=-\tfrac47$,
$a_2=\tfrac{16}{49}$
and

\begin{align} 
y(x)&=\tfrac{16}{49}\,x^2-\tfrac47
.
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: It depends on which form of parabola someone use. It seems that the OP uses $y=ax^2+b$

Comment: @callculus : Thanks, I've added the treatment for this special case.

Comment: @g.kov Thanks for that! Superb explanation. May I ask which programme you used to get the graph visualisation?